# Recycler view lost after fragment replacement

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a single activity which replaces a fragment containing a recycler view with a fragment containing details of the selected viewholder item. When the back button is pressed the fragment containing the recycler view is restored but the recycler view items are no longer displayed.  However, views are restored upon device rotation. All model data is stored in a SQLite database and the adapter list is updated on resume of its fragment .

```
CrimeListFragment.Java

public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {

    private Callbacks callbacks;

    public interface Callbacks {
        public void onItemSelected(UUID id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        callbacks = (Callbacks) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        callbacks = null;
    }

    private RecyclerView crimeListRecycler;
    private CrimeListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false);

        crimeListRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.crime_list);
        crimeListRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        updateUI();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_crime_list, menu);

        MenuItem showSubtitle = menu.findItem(R.id.show_subtitle);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.new_crime:
                Crime crime = new Crime();
                CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).addCrime(crime);
                /*Intent intent = CrimeActivity.createIntent(getActivity(), crime.getId());
                startActivity(intent);*/
                callbacks.onItemSelected(crime.getId());
                return true;
            default:
                return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        List<Crime> crimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();
        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new CrimeListAdapter(crimes);
            crimeListRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            adapter.setCrimesList(crimes);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public class CrimeListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeListAdapter.CrimeHolder> {

        private List<Crime> crimeList;

        public CrimeListAdapter(List<Crime> crimes) {
            crimeList = crimes;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false);

            return new CrimeHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CrimeHolder holder, int position) {
            Crime crime = crimeList.get(position);
            holder.bind(crime);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return crimeList.size();
        }

        public void setCrimesList(List<Crime> crimes) {
            crimeList = crimes;
        }

        public class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

            private Crime crime;

            private TextView crimeTitleTextView;
            private TextView crimeDateTextView;

            public CrimeHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                crimeTitleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
                crimeDateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            public void bind(Crime crime) {
                this.crime = crime;
                crimeTitleTextView.setText(crime.getTitle());
                crimeDateTextView.setText(crime.getDate().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callbacks.onItemSelected(crime.getId());
                /*Intent intent = CrimeActivity.createIntent(getActivity(), crime.getId());
                startActivity(intent);*/
            }
        }
    }
}

MasterActivity

public class MasterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CrimeListFragment.Callbacks {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new CrimeListFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(UUID id) {
        Fragment fragment = CrimeFragment.newInstance(id);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code. Something to check when you replace/add your fragment on top of recyclerview fragment.

Comment: Just did. Hope that helps